# Listar todos os dados do form via POST ou GET

Tags: php, javascript

Estou com um problema que não consigo resolver tenho estou terminando um site que será usado para um bolão de futebol, segue o link (http://bolaobr.arwmontagememanutencao.com.br) na página "apostadores" exibe uma lista de apostadores cadastrados com a pontuação de cada um e no final da linha um botão para buscar o resultado, que é enviado via post para página que exibe os pontos e a soma dos mesmos, gostaria de uma ajuda para capturar todos os apostadores e somar seus pontos.

Abaixo o link do script de envio (página apostadores) que estar em um txt 
http://bolaobr.arwmontagememanutencao.com.br/bolaobr/script01_ajuda.txt

Eu gostaria de saber como capturar todos os apostadores via post ou get e somar seus respectivos pontos no final da linha que seria a ultima coluna(td), a principio consigo capturar apenas 1 apostador e somar seus pontos via post ou get. Parece que a página que recebe os dados não ler toda url.

Esses são os parâmetros recebidos na index.

```
index.php?rodada=1&apt=Azarado&rodada=1&apt=F2p&jogo1=7&jogo2=10&busca=Buscar+Resultado&rodada=1&apt=luizinho&rodada=1&apt=M2c&jogo1=7&jogo2=7&jogo3=7&jogo4=10
```

Só não consigo capturar o último.

```
apt=M2c&jogo1=7&jogo2=7&jogo3=7&jogo4=10
```

Gostaria de capturar todos e somar o seus valores.

Comment: voce pode postar a estrutura da tabela?

Comment: A pergunta não é clara, parece que você quer que nós criemos um algoritmo e passamos o código pronto pra você.
Seria mais objetivo você postar exatamente qual é o seu problema.
[help/dont-ask]

Comment: Não quero codigo pronto amigo, tanto que postei o link do meu codigo que faz o envio dos dados via POST, não postei o codigo porque é muito grande, inclusive postei o link do site que estou construindo. Eu consigo capturar apenas um apostador e somar seus pontos gostaria de ajuda para capturar todos os apostadores e somar os pontos, ja tentei via GET e vi que todos os dados estão indo para url mas só consigo capturar um segue o link do script da página que recebe os dados http://bolaobr.arwmontagememanutencao.com.br/bolaobr/script01_ajuda2.txt

Comment: Talvez essa referencia te ajude com a soma dos valores, da uma olhava e veja se é isso que você precisa, caso contrario seja mais claro em sua necessidade. [Somar Valores em Tabelas](http://www.guj.com.br/11853-somar-valores-tabela-php-e-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ola a todos e obrigado aqueles que tentaram me ajudar.
Graças Deus consegui fazer o calculo com um "array" e "array_search" segue abaixo o link da tabela com completa.
http://bolaobr.arwmontagememanutencao.com.br/bolaobr/scriptForm.txt
Segue abaixo o codigo para o calculo

```
$valores = array($valor, $valor1, $valor2, $valor3, $valor4, 

$valor5, $valor6, $valor7, $valor8, $valor9 );
               if(array_search($valor, $valores) !== false){
                   $calculando = $valor + $valor1 + $valor2 + $valor3 + 

$valor4 + $valor5 + $valor6 + $valor7 + $valor8 + $valor9;
                   echo "$calculando";
               }else{
                }
```

Este é o link do site que terminei da uma olhada na página "Apostadores" e vejam o resultado.
http://bolaobr.arwmontagememanutencao.com.br/bolaobr

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a `$_REQUEST` para pegar todos os valores e em seguida passar eles para as variaveis;

```
 // Usando o laço foreach...
foreach ($_REQUEST as $nome_campo => $valor_campo) {

//Exibi o campo e o valor contido
echo $nome_campo . " => " . $valor_campo . "<br />";

//Cria uma variavel para somar os campos
$somar += $valor_campo;

}
//Exibi os valores somados
echo $somar;
```

Você pode simplesmente deixar a variavel de soma dentro do foreach para fazer a contagem e depois exibi-la.

Comment: Ola Rafael retorna a mesma coisa, antes so captura o ultimo apostador.